# Render on other render targets starting from one already rendered on

Tags: opengl, rendering, rendertargets

I have to perform a double pass convolution on a texture that is actually the color attachment of another render target, and store it in the color attachment of ANOTHER render target.  This must be done multiple time, but using the same texture as starting point

What I do now is (a bit abstracted, but what I have abstract is guaranteed to work singularly)

```
renderOnRT(firstTarget); // This is working. 

for each other RT currRT{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, currRT.frameBufferID);    
    programX.use();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, firstTarget.colorAttachmentID);
    programX.setUniform1i("colourTexture",0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, firstTarget.depthAttachmentID);
    programX.setUniform1i("depthTexture",1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadBuffID); // quadBuffID is a VBO for a screen aligned quad. It is fine.
    programX.vertexAttribPointer(POSITION_ATTRIBUTE, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,4);

    programY.use();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, currRT.colorAttachmentID); // The second pass is done on the previous pass
    programY.setUniform1i("colourTexture",0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, currRT.depthAttachmentID);
    programY.setUniform1i("depthTexture",1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadBuffID);
    programY.vertexAttribPointer(POSITION_ATTRIBUTE, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
}
```

The problem is that I end up with black textures and not the wanted result.

The GLSL programs program(X,Y) works fine, already tested on single targets.

Is there something stupid I am missing?

Even an hint is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The for contains the double pass convolution step?

Comment: @Cristina The programs programX and programY are build with the shaders that perform the convolution, they do work as they give the wanted result with a single target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later edit:

There is a feedback loop in the way you are rendering, read the code again more carefully.

You are drawing to `currRT`, the first convolution step fills in `currRT.colorTexture`. Then in the second draw call you use `currRT.colorTexture` for the second step of the convolution. This produces undefined behavior in GL.

You should use two frame buffers, one that does the first step of the convolution and another that does the second step.

Comment: I'm aware of that, when I render it on screen any of those texture I got black ones. And the program I use to render to screen I'm 100% sure works (works fine with other textures).

Comment: @JTulip see my update answer. Read the code again more carefully.

Comment: Ah! Sorry! Yes, I didn't thought that it was both writing and reading from same texture, thank you very much! I've solved with a temporary FBO!